# Does the Wadea Al Fayoume stabbing qualify as a hate crime?

Tags: hate-crime

Wadea Al Fayoume was stabbed 26 times Saturday by his family’s landlord in Plainfield Township, Illinois per: https://www.cnn.com/2023/10/17/us/6-year-old-boy-palestinian-boy-chicago-profile/index.html

For this question, Assume that all statements in the CNN article are true facts, do the facts support a hate crime charge?

Comment: Without looking at all the evidence, this is merely speculation.

Comment: @user71659 I don't think it's speculation.  The OP qualifies their question by asking the reader to assume that all statements reported in the CNN article are facts and make a determination based on law thereon.  Voting to leave question open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the Wadea Al Fayoume stabbing qualify as a hate crime?

According to Assistant State’s Attorney Michael Fitzgerald and the Will County Sheriff, this incident it does qualify as a hate crime. A [TV news report from today](https://www.nbcchicago.com/news/local/chicago-suburban-palestinian-community-remember-muslim-boy-killed-in-hate-crime-as-kind-energetic/3252555/) (Tuesday, October 17, 2023) states:

> Earlier Monday, Czuba made his first court appearance on murder,
> attempted murder and hate crime charges. In detailing the charges
> Sunday, the Will County Sheriff’s Office determined “both victims in
> this brutal attack were targeted by the suspect due to them being
> Muslim and the ongoing Middle Eastern conflict involving Hamas and the
> Israelis.”

The [Illinois hate crime statute](https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/documents/072000050k12-7.1.htm) states in the pertinent part:

> **A person commits hate crime when, by reason of the actual or perceived** race, color, creed, **religion**, ancestry, gender, sexual
> orientation, physical or mental disability, citizenship, immigration
> status, **or national origin of another individual or group of
> individuals**, regardless of the existence of any other motivating
> factor or factors, **he or she commits assault, battery, aggravated
> assault**, intimidation, stalking, cyberstalking, misdemeanor theft,
> criminal trespass to residence, misdemeanor criminal damage to
> property, criminal trespass to vehicle, criminal trespass to real
> property, mob action, disorderly conduct, transmission of obscene
> messages, harassment by telephone, or harassment through electronic
> communications as these crimes are defined in Sections 12-1, 12-2,
> 12-3(a), 12-7.3, 12-7.5, 16-1, 19-4, 21-1, 21-2, 21-3, 25-1, 26-1,
> 26.5-1, 26.5-2, paragraphs (a)(1), (a)(2), and (a)(3) of Section 12-6, and paragraphs (a)(2) and (a)(5) of Section 26.5-3 of this Code,
> respectively.

720 ILCS 5/12-7.1(a).

The remainder of the statute sets forth which penalties apply in which circumstances for violations of the statute, and defines the term sexual orientation.

The defendant allegedly committed battery, assault, or aggravated assault against the mother (who lived) allegedly motivated by religion or national origin. Therefore, this constitutes a hate crime under Illinois law (assuming that the facts alleged in the media regarding this incident are true).

The stabbing of the child, because the child died, is murder, which is not eligible for being classified as a hate crime in Illinois law.

Comment: "...this incident ...does qualify as a hate crime". I would argue that it only qualifies as a hate crime if there is a *conviction* under that statute. Nothing matters until/unless proven beyond reasonable doubt in the court. The state's attorney(s) may choose to charge whatever they will, it doesn't mean the charge(s) will stick...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it The question states (and the answer assumes, without stating so explicitly): "Assume that all statements in the CNN article are true facts". So, given those hypothetical facts, it does qualify as a hate crime. Of course, it is entirely possible that one or more facts alleged by the prosecutor and sheriff are not found to be true at trial, but that would be beyond the scope of what was asked. Put another way, the question is really asking if the crime as alleged would constitute a hate crime if those facts are proven beyond a reasonable doubt in a trial.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Put yet another way, what the question is really asking is what one must prove legally in Illinois to obtain a hate crime conviction under Illinois law.